# HTML Jinja not working with moment module

Tags: html, flask, jinja2, momentjs

Hi I have a table with 2 columns where I show the name of the person, and the last time he was connected.

My html code looks something like this:

```
<div id="refresh">
    <div id="time">
        <table id="list">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Connection</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Philip</td>
                <td>{{ moment(current_time).fromNow() }}</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Where the current_time variable is sent when a user is connected.

And I have a js to refresh the table every 5 seconds:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval("my_function();",5000); 
    function my_function(){
        $('#ref').load(location.href + ' #ref > *');
    }            
</script>
```

When I first see the table, everything works fine, I can see the name and the last seen which is 'a few seconds ago'. But when the function `my_function` refresh the div with the table, the value from last connection **disappears**, and it never reappears.

I was thinking of only refreshing the first column but it doesn't work either. Someone knows how could it be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a short example, with using moment js
https://jsfiddle.net/eagwmsxj/12/

```
<script>
    setInterval(update, 500);
    function update(a, b)
    {
      document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = moment()
      console.log("Update")
    }
</script>

<div id="refresh">
    <div id="time">
        <table id="list">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Last Connection</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Philip</td>
                <td id="time"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```